# Remove delete option for broken file shortcuts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, links

In Windows 10, if a link / file shortcut is "broken", a error message is shown:

```
The item ‘[filename]’ that this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved.
Do you want to delete it?
```

This is also the case for e.g. network-links (e.g. `\\hostname\sub1\sub2` or `\\hostname\sub3\file1.txt`). If you temporarily are not connected to the network, Windows "classifies" them as broken (which frankly does not make much sense in the first place). It gets pretty annoying if you hit yes by accident.

Is it possible to deactivate this dialogue, or more specifically the delete option? I don't mind to deactivate it all together (not just for network links). I would prefer a registry fix, but I take any solution...

Comment: Why don’t you just fix the shortcut so it refers to a file that actually exists?

Comment: @Ramhound.. because it is a network shortcut and he isn't connected.. there is nothing to fix. If it really bothers you and you really need the shortcut.. why not use a shortcut to cmd.exe /c "start THINGY" and change the icon to whatever you want.. would this work?

Comment: There is a Hotfix for windows 7 - there might be something similar for windows 10:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2642357/broken-shortcuts-are-deleted-from-the-desktop-in-windows-7#reginfo

Comment: @KalamalkaKid thanks for the suggestion but as far as I can see the registry switch only applies to automated/scheduled cleanup tasks. In my case, the check is being applied on accessing the file-shortcut. I was hoping there is a registry switch to disable it as well. I think I saw simimlar solutions for Win10 as well, but they too didn't apply.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas mainly those are shortcuts to folders (and some files) on the networkdrive via a networkpath e.g. `\\hostname\sub1\sub2` or `\\hostname\sub3\file1.txt`. I have quite a few of them so creating them manually is out of the question. I'll have to check if I can write a script that goes recursive through all my folders and creates/exchanges them in bulk. The problem with the solution is, that the links get open in a new explorer window, and not into the same one, do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas But for now I'll do it for my main shortcuts anyway. Feel free to post an answer, so at least I can give you a +1 (or mark it as a solution, if it turns out that there really is no option to turn it off). Thanks, that was a good idea.

Comment: I think the dialogue is tied to the explorer.exe and not the registry (i did a quick search in regedit), so what @SeñorCMasMas mentioned might be the only available option ...

Comment: @hextech I fear so too, but maybe s.o. can think of a different workaround (that won't open a second Explorer window)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, until someone comes along with a better solution, I suggest that you create a shortcut to cmd.exe and use it to launch the target instead.

1. Create a shortcut to cmd.exe.
2. Rename it to the thing you are trying to replace.
3. Edit the properties of your new shortcut
4. In the target field, after cmd.exe, add ***/c "start [path to your application, document, or network path]"***
5. Click the "change icon" button and make it spiffy
6. Use the "Run:" dropdown and change to "Minimized"

It sucks.. but it's better than windows warning you that the path doesn't exist or accidentally deleting the shortcut.

I don't know if you program or not, but one could write a program to search all shortcuts and make automatic replacement shortcuts for them.  For a real explorer and COM badass.. they could even replace the shortcut handler and make this problem go away in any way chosen.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I won't get around programing. I do code but mainly prototype database stuff, a few tools here and there, but nothing that's integrated in Windows so far. Feel free to give any pointers, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

This error message only appears when a shortcut is created through New -> Shortcut in File Explorer. If you drag the folder icon from the Explorer address bar into the Explorer window, it will create a shortcut to the current folder, but if the folder is deleted and you double-click the shortcut, Explorer changes the shortcut's destination to the shortcut's current directory. I've been trying to find a solution to this since Windows Vista or even earlier. If a shortcut is created thru New -> Shortcut, Explorer will check the following values in the registry:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

```
NoResolveSearch -> 1

NoResolveTrack -> 1
```

Means no search for linked folder. But with a shortcut created by dragging as explained above these reg values are not checked at all, Explorer simply runs to Windows Search:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{934D4698-6A59-48f8-9F29-9FB30670320E}

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\StructuredQuery.dll
```

and happily searches for the missing folder. Of course, it fails to find anything and breaks the shortcut as explained above.

Very annoying, because a shortcut may be invalid currently, but valid under other circumstances. Like, I have two Windows systems on two NVMes, if a shortcut points to:

%systemroot%\bla

it may be present on one Win installation, but not on the second. So if I am currently on the second Windows, I accidentally click that shortcut, but for current Windows "%systemroot%" is "c:\windows", so it searches for "C:\windows\bla", while the shortcut is actually meant for "D:\windows\bla", you get the point.

It must be a bug. One, which MS has not been able to fix in the last 20 years.